Why was squid game a surprise to the VIPs?
At the end of Squid Game, the Front Man reveals the final round to be "squid game," which seems to shock all of the VIPs as if they hadn't seen it used in the games before.
But if the entire title of this annual event is "Squid Game", and it's been going on for years, then why are they surprised? Were there some years they didn't have the actual squid game as part of it? But then that wouldn't make sense as to why it's called that.
It seems like the VIPs would have seen other games from previous years as well, although I'm not sure if this is technically verified.
Is there an answer to this?

I think the most likely explanation is that the games are not referred to as Squid Game or no longer referred to as Squid Games with the international group of VIPs.
The Games are not verbally referred to as Squid Game
The TV show opens with a description of Squid Game and the show is called that, but the event itself is only referred to as "games" or "the games" by the organizers or VIPs.
The games take place in other countries as well
Conversation between VIPs imply that games take place in other countries in addition to Korea. From some transcripts.

[VIP 2] The games of this edition have been amazing.
[VIP 3] Right. The contest in Korea was the best.

Since Squid Game is a Korean playground game, it would not make sense for the series of events to be called Squid Game.
Apparent Inconsistencies
This interpretation is consistent with the surprise the VIPs have over the Squid Game name and their unfamiliarity with the game.
However there are inconsistencies with this interpretation.  In S1E5 when Hwang Jun-ho is digging through filing cabinets he finds records of previous players including his Brother. English close captioning shows:
2015 28TH SQUID GAME
PLAYER 132, HWANG IN-HO

However using Google translate reveals this is over-zealous close caption writers.  The document is simply "ROUND 6 WINNERS", with a column for "meeting" and the row says "28 times" presumably a poor translation of 28th. So it is called 'meeting' here in the document.
The brother then digs through other files, which are marked as "Squid Archives" in English. This is the only appearance of the word Squid that I can find in relation to the games or the organization. Perhaps the Korean (founders?) of the games call the organization that, and maybe the games were once called that, but as far as the current games are concerned they have internationalized it and dropped the Korean specific term.  Hence the VIPs being puzzled.

But when the cop was looking through old files to search for his brother the papers all said squid game

You are correct - at least the close caption transcripts say "28th SQUID GAME" in S1E5.  I'll add that inconsistency to the answer at some point today.  I think the fact that (a) we never hear Squid Game used verbally, (b) the fact that it is also other countries and (c) the VIPs are suprised at the same suggest that perhaps this is either an inconsistency in the show or the closed captions are infact incorrect translations of the documents.

@Awtsmoos I've dug into that a bit more with Google Translate and it seems to be an incorrect (or over zealous) translation of the document by the close-caption writers.  I think it is likely that at this time the games are no longer called Squid Games, though perhaps they or the organization were at one point

Interesting. But what about the card that the players are given with the phone number? Doesn't that say squid game also? It's also interesting that the games are in other countries as well, Film Theory YouTuber disagrees and said it seems implied that they are in an island in the justification of North Korea which is how they were able to get away with it... But does that imply that these VIPs were only in Korea for the first time that year? Based on the East the front man talks to them it seems like they knew him from before, but I could be wrong

@Estem - quickly watched the part of S1E1 where he is given the card by the 'recruiter' on the train platform.  It has the phone number on one side and the square-triangle-circle icons on the other side.

The card they are given to allow them to rejoin the games just says a time and 'location as before', and the icons on the reverse side.

I just assumed the squares and triangles were part of the Korean language to spell out "squid game", I guess I didn't realize they were basically nothing.. But with this answer, did the VIPs never before see the Korean games before? Or was this the first year that Korea had it's own popular game on it?

Hard to say, and there may have been only a few of the VIPs in that conversation so perhaps they were relatively new to either the games in general or the popular game in particular.
